# How to specify a LINK in org-anniversary to jump from org-agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, hyperlinks

The idea is to add a LINK after

```
%%(org-anniversary 2006 3 21) World Down Syndrome Day (%d years) <LINK>
```

So when I see it in my agenda for that day, I can click and jump to a ORG heading in a ORG buffer where I can learn more about the event. I tried using `C-c l (org-store-link)`, but it fails. Any help, thanks!

Comment: If you add it manually `[[https://www.google.com][Google]]`, does it work? Where are you trying to do `C-c l`? How does it fail? Is there an error message? How do you know it fails? DId you try to insert the link you stored with `C-c C-l`? If you want help, then you have to provide all the relevant information, so people *can* help you!

Comment: Thanks, I solved this problem. With http links it does work. I wanted to create a link to a heading in an org file, but wasn't using ID. When I use ID, it works. Otherwise, it doesn't.